# Difference between "opacity" and "opaqueness"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns, suffixes

What is the difference in the meaning und usage of the words *opacity* and *opaqueness*?

Comment: My hunch would tell me opacity is the degree of opaqueness. But I don't have any reliable sources on that.

Comment: _Opaqueness_ looks weird, _opacity_ doesn't.

Comment: I left my answer on the reCAPTCHA for the past 15 hours, just realized now. I agree that *opaqueness* is an awkward looking, sounding usage. As @SingerOfTheFall said, *opacity* as a noun just seems better. I would prefer structuring a sentence to use *opaque* instead of *opaqueness* if at all possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference between the two is more one of actual use than one of nuance.  For simple meaning, the OED provides:

> - ***opaqueness*** — the quality of being opaque; opacity.
> - ***opacity*** — The quality or fact of being opaque; opaqueness.

The earliest citation given for *opaqueness*  in English is 1647, and that of *opacity* is 1611.  *Opacity* is a French loanword, or was.  It comes from

> French *opacité* (15-16th c. in Hatz.-Darm.), ad. Latin *opācitās*, f. *opācus* **opaque**.

Whereas *opaqueness* was formed simply by adding the normal English derivational suffix *-ness* to the existing word *opaque*.  *Opacity* has several senses and subsenses listed in the OED, while *opaqueness* has only the one I have provided above.

But as I said, the real difference is how often each is used relative to the other. [This Google N-Gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opacity%2Copaqueness&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that in actual printed use, *opacity* is favored over *opaqueness* by a favor of around 15 to 1:

[image: Google N-Gram showing 15:1 preference of opacity over opaqueness]

Although these words aren’t normally made into plurals, they can be, and sometimes must be.  Here the comparative euphony of *opacities* over the Gollum-like *opaquenesses* wins hands down in [this other Google N-Gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opacities%2Copaquenesses&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image: Google N-Gram of opacities compared with opaquenesses]

In actual examples, here are the first three recent usage citations obtained by those N-Grams, first for ***opaquenesses***:

1. It involves the acceptance of others by means of an indifference to, or neglect of, their differences, of all the opaquenesses and knobby protrusions that make it diflicult to swallow their souls into one's own.  [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=XEaYu1ZgkzEC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22opaquenesses%22&source=bl&ots=JMIxrPLIl2&sig=vOAU0RQ_AYxGQji8SmT9HW5l0ao&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ha5-UL2zI8TjqAGF_4GwAg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22opaquenesses%22&f=false)
2. He and Kistin had visited the hospitals once and seen briefly the doctorless, nurse- less place where those returning from enclayment were given a chance to cure themselves of the dreadful opaquenesses caused by lying, stealing, false pride, and the like. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=U4Z-dUl68L0C&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22opaquenesses%22&source=bl&ots=23_gQoH8JT&sig=d1LETFt48xqHEOCFJk-nsPyvY0Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ha5-UL2zI8TjqAGF_4GwAg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22opaquenesses%22&f=false)
3. Blackmur acquired great influence as a critic because he tackled the difficulties and opaquenesses of such modern poets as Yeats, Eliot, Stevens and Hart Crane head-on in a commentary that was subtle, discriminating, illuminating and ... [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=UwuFAAAAIAAJ&q=%22opaquenesses%22&dq=%22opaquenesses%22&source=bl&ots=hui_Lq0SmJ&sig=hJF121n1RTmnRR5u95QC3Exd7iE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ha5-UL2zI8TjqAGF_4GwAg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw)

And then for ***opacities***:

1. The opacities are classified according to the diameter of the predominant opacities: [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ha21u07zrNYC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22opacities%22&source=bl&ots=gcsjQVU1QR&sig=8ZVnENQ6qFtwgwy0t8jO6Rtv_nQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jq9-UKLgNJTJqQGElIFA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22opacities%22&f=false)
2. In this system, the size, shape, and profusion of opacities on the radiographs of patients with penumoconiosis are classified in a detailed fashion by trained observers, using a set of standard radiographs. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=2V1Xzs2mD3QC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=%22opacities%22&source=bl&ots=9Ml8RejHVF&sig=t0Zy8lHuc-uOcgzp7O9jAvwdewQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jq9-UKLgNJTJqQGElIFA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22opacities%22&f=false)
3. Large capacities (greater than 1 cm in diameter) correspond to lesions of complicated pneumoconiosis (progressive massive fibrosis) and are classified into categories—A, B, and C—depending on their size. [[citation]](http://books.google.com/books?id=TQju7e__pRIC&pg=PA853&lpg=PA853&dq=%22opacities%22&source=bl&ots=6YMqVXnHbJ&sig=QWUixHVhWG11rJ-AGjeedIj76jw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jq9-UKLgNJTJqQGElIFA&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22opacities%22&f=false)

In summary, I would strongly recommend using ***opacity*** over ***opaqueness***.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely a new answer; I'd like to modify the idea provided by @tchrist:

> opaqueness — the **state** or fact of being opaque.
>   opacity — The **degree** of being opaque.

*This material is not suitable due to its **opaqueness**.

This material is not suitable because of its high **opacity***.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Answer (score 2):

"Opacity" is usually used in technical contexts, and invokes a nuance of it being a measurable quantity. "Opaqueness" is normally used when speaking colloquially, and can also be used metaphorically to mean "incomprehensibility resulting from obscurity of meaning" (Mirriam-Webster). To that end, it would sound strange to give an actual measurement of "opaqueness". For example:

> This fluid has an ?opaqueness of 40 square meters per kg.

This sentence sounds strange.

> This fluid has an opacity of 40 square meters per kg.

This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Opacity is a measure of light blocking (non-penetration) by a material. 
It can go from 0% (transparent; no blockage) to 50% (translucent; partial blockage) to 100% (opaque - complete blockage).

By definition, opaque means light cannot penetrate (100% opacity).  If light could even partially penetrate, it would be translucent, not opaque.

So opaqueness is the state or condition of being opaque (no light can pass through).  Opacity is a measure of how much light cannot pass through.

Comment: add a citation to support your answer if you please

Comment: You can look up "opacity" and "vagueness" in any English dictionary but dictionaries do NOT explain these terms very well.  I am a native English American teacher trying to explain the subtle difference in my own words.  I cannot prove my answer with a citation.  If a "citation" is required, then simply delete my reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add this thought. While I heartily agree that *opacity* is highly preferable to *opaqueness*, I ended up on this page because I was concerned that the particular audience for which I'm writing at the moment might stumble over *opacity* or not catch the meaning at all, where the point of the sentence is to harshly criticize the addressee for deliberately making a process opaque for the purpose of concealing cheating.  The concept has to leap off the page and smack the reader up side the head to achieve its greatest effect.

I've never thought about when "-icity" should be used and when "-ness" would be proper.  Considering it now based on my own use and experience without any investigation, it seems to me that it may be as simple as whether 1) one of them grates on the ear, or b) adding "-icity" makes the noun too dissimilar from the adjective for the relation to be clear, or even to be recognizable at all.  Consider *opaque* and *unique*.  I may be mistaking familiarity for connection as to *opaque* and *opacity*, but *unicity* for *unique* definitely doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, Geoffrey. At least some attempt at rigourousness and objectivity is expected in answers on ELU; answers lacking evidence of research come across as (and may merely be) one person's opinions. And even Professors of Linguistics have their differences. This would be a valid 'comment' on ELU. // tchrist's answer is by far the best here, and shows the standard hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

I use **opacity** as a parameter between 0 and 100%, when describing the degree of transparency of something, most often web markup. For example, `opacity = 0.2` would be very close to transparent, or "see through". A more typical value for my purposes is `opacity = 0.8` which is only slightly transparent. Of course, a value of 1.0 or 100% means totally opaque, solid, not gauzy or translucent at all.

**Opaqueness** is more familiar to me as word used for prose communication, rather than webpage design. Although the word is legitimate, I don't find it easy to use in context. It seems more idiomatic to describe something as "more opaque" or "less opaque", although an example of usage of would be to say something had "an aspect of opaqueness to it".

Answer (score -4):

The difference in use is that you would use *opacity* to refer to understanding, when something is difficult to understand or obscure.

[*opacity, n.*](http://oed.com/view/Entry/131669?redirectedFrom=opacity#eid)

*a. Obscurity of meaning; resistance to interpretation; impenetrability; an instance of this. rare before 20th cent.*

or

[*opacity*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opacity)
noun

*the quality of lacking transparency or translucence:
thinner paints need black added to increase opacity*

*the quality of being obscure in meaning:
the difficulty and opacity in Barthes' texts*

*Opaqueness* is the noun to the adjective *opaque*, and would be used to describe the extent to which something is opaque, or able to transmit light.

[*opaque*](http://oed.com/view/Entry/131685)

*A. adj.*

2.

*a. Not transmitting light, not transparent or translucent; impenetrable to sight. Also fig.*

or

[*Definition of opaque*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opaque?q=opaqueness#opaque__7)

*not able to be seen through; not transparent:
bottles filled with a pale opaque liquid*

*(especially of language) hard or impossible to understand:
technical jargon that was opaque to her*

Used figuratively, in an understanding = seeing the light sort of way, the two words can become very similar, as shown particularly by the Oxford Dictionaries entries.

*Opacity* also has several technical uses. As pointed out by several posters, it is used in programming. It is wrong to imagine that language exists only for programmers though - *opacity* also has a technical use in physics, and in linguistics, and in photography, and in the paint industry, and probably others that I am unaware of. For these localised uses it is probably better to ask in the appropriate forums.

Comment: -1: I think this is a spurious distinction.

Comment: This answer is confused and wrong.  If, as you actually now illustrate, the adjective can apply to both understanding and optics then opaqueness can too (you offer no evidence to the contrary).  This allows it the same range of meaning as **Opacity**, so then it just comes down to relative frequency of usage.

Comment: Usage is exactly whatvthe OP asked about - scroll up and look. OED lists obscurity as the main meaning for *opacity* and transmission of light for *opaqueness*. I understand that you consider yourself a higher authority than OED, but in reality the petty pedantry displayed by amateurs such as yourself is ruining this site. It should be a fun place to be, but it isn't.